pcsd service not starting inside container when selinux is in permissive mode on ec2 host
I am trying to create a 3 app and 1 db cluster on ec2 host. on ec2 host selinux is enabled and in permissive mode. pcs, pacemaker and corosync is installed inside docker image. once containers starts and i am able to login into 1st app container namely app1 and perform following:

ping app2/app3
ssh app2/app3

when i check pcsd status, i get following output:
sudo systemctl status pcsd.service -l
Can anyone please help me fix this issue.
Investigation note:

pcsd-ruby.service status is active and running.
No entry for pcsd in audit.log nor in /var/log/messages

